# How to defer a slow database operation with SQLAlchemy / Python

Tags: postgresql, rest, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I've got a REST interface to a database, implemented in Python FastAPI + SQLAlchemy. I want to run some (relatively) costly operations on my data, such as calculating cryptographic hashes or signatures. My hope is to be able to:

1. Perform the insert, so that all referential integrity is checked by the database.
2. Return the REST response to the front-end (primary key of insert).
3. Asynchronously calculate the costly hash/signature/whatever, and update into the DB (same table).

I'd prefer to have a cross-database solution, but it seems running a trigger on insert/update might be the way to go. If so, my target in production is PostgreSQL.

Does anyone have a suggested approach they'd favour?

Comment: FastAPI has a concept of [background tasks](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/), perhaps it will meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to separate the concerns.

- Build a fast REST service that does items 1 and 2 (concern: consistent data persistence);
- Create a scheduled job that does item 3 in the background using [pgAgent](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/pgagent.html) or s/th similar (concern: data "decoration") or use a notify/listen setup to invoke a separate process.

Running a trigger would do the actions synchronously. As far as I understand this is not your intention.

Comment: Your answer helped me realise that I had made the erroneous assumption that triggers were asynchronous, but duh! they have to run in the transaction context. And decorator is the perfect word for the pattern here. **pgAgent** looks very useful! But the timing I'm trying to achieve here is nearer realtime. The pg listen/notify with an independent daemon listener might be a good alternative solution.

Comment: Sounds very good. An `after insert or update` trigger only issues a notification (using `pg_notify` function) and leaves quickly then the daemon listener jumps in and does the heavy lifting. I have edited my answer to include it.

Comment: I think that's a super combination of options. I'll try to develop it so that pgAgent can also call the daemon, so that if any work is missed, it can be executed as a cleanup on schedule.